# How can I have 40 connections per node to Cassandra database using Pelops client?

Tags: java, cassandra, pelops

By default `Pelops will have 20 connections per node`-

I was thinking to modify that to have around `40 connections per node`. So how can I do that in Pelops? Currently, I am creating pool like this-

```
private void createPool() {
    Pelops.addPool(getPoolName(), getCluster(), getKeyspace());

}

/**
 * Gets the cluster information
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Cluster getCluster() {

    Config casconf = new Config(ModelConstants.CASSANDRA_PORT, true, 0); 

    Cluster cluster= new Cluster(nodes, casconf, ModelConstants.NODE_DISCOVERY);

    return cluster; 
}

/**
 * Get the keyspace name
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String getKeyspace() {
    return keyspace;
}

/**
 * Get the pool name
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String getPoolName() {
    return poolName;
}
```

Can anyone provide an example for that so that I can modify that to hold 40 connection per node? Thanks for the help.

**Updated Code:-**

```
    CommonsBackedPool.Policy pt = new Policy();
    pt.setMaxActivePerNode(40);

    OperandPolicy op = new OperandPolicy();

    Pelops.addPool(getPoolName(), getCluster(), getKeyspace(), pt, op);
```

I was not sure whether I did the right thing above or not? let me know if it looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [JavaDocs for Pelops](http://stephenc.github.io/scale7-pelops/apidocs/org/scale7/cassandra/pelops/Pelops.html) you would use the *other* `Pelops.addPool()` method that allows you to supply an instance of [CommonsBackedPool.Policy](http://stephenc.github.io/scale7-pelops/apidocs/org/scale7/cassandra/pelops/pool/CommonsBackedPool.Policy.html) which is what controls that.

Comment: I updated my question with some changes that I thought of but not able to make that code working. As I am not sure what should I add in other methods. Can you help me out here with a simple example so that I can understand better? Thanks for the help.